# When my page loads in IE, the window immediately jumps behind other windows

Tags: javascript, windows, internet-explorer

A user recently reported this mystifying bug: On [one of my pages](http://www.scottseverance.us/html/time_calculator.htm):

- When it loads in IE (observed in IE8, it's status in other versions is unknown); and
- At least one other window is open behind IE

The following happens:

- The IE window moves behind all other windows; and
- It keeps its focus. This means that the window's taskbar button is depressed and the page receives all expected key events, even while the window is completely hidden.
- Trying to bring IE to the foreground is futile. It just immediately jumps back again as long as there's another window to hide behind.

I'm by no means an IE expert. I keep an XP virtual machine around for those rare occasions when I *must* use IE or Windows. So I'm unfamiliar with how to even begin tracking down this bug. Can someone help me out in pinpointing this bug?

Comment: I bet it has something to do with that "setBlur()" function that gets called for IE8 and 9.  Try making that quit doing anything.

Comment: @Pointy: Thanks. It seems that IE8 doesn't like that function. Do you (or anyone else) know whether this bug also occurs in IE9? I don't have a Vista or newer machine, so I can't install IE9.

Comment: As a follow-up, IE9 is the same as IE8 in this respect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have had the same problem in the past - the body is being blurred [document.body.blur() only works in IE]. The function doing this is setBlur() in your source.

Current version:

```
function setBlur(items) {
    var item;
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        item = items[i];
        if (item.id == "search-box-wrapper") continue;
        if (item.children) setBlur(item.children);
        try {
            item.onfocus = function() {
                this.blur();
            };
        } catch (e) {
            if (console) console.warn(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Version excluding body blurring (solving your problem hopefully):

```
function setBlur(items) {
    var item;
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        item = items[i];
        if (item.id == "search-box-wrapper" || (item.tagName).toUpperCase() == "BODY") continue;
        if (item.children) setBlur(item.children);
        try {
            item.onfocus = function() {
                this.blur();
            };
        } catch (e) {
            if (console) console.warn(e);
        }
    }
}
```

This makes sure the function setBlur() cannot be used to blur the body by accident, although does not address the function which calls setBlur([document.body, ..., ...]).

Comment: I belatedly noticed that I never accepted an answer. I applied an alternate method for avoiding blurring the body, and the bug is now dead.